# It is reasonable to expect a contractor to replace the last foot of HVAC duct work, the connection between the insulated duct and the register?

Tags: hvac, contractors, ducts

The contract was to replace an antiquated HVAC and duct work. Since the registers are a standard size, would this connection also be a standard pre-fabricated part?
What is that last connection called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe it's called a "boot", and yes, they're generally pre-fabricated.

However, if the existing ones are in good shape, they shouldn't need replacing.  If they're damaged, then the reasonableness depends on what your contract says.

Comment: The registers were in good shape, although full of dust and debris. Contractor could have shown some hustle and at least cleaned them while he had access to them.